# Displaying Unicode character from it's number using PHP

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, symbols

Alright & I've a query. Is there any way to display Unicode symbol from it's unique number. For eg. I've the Integral symbol (∫) & It's Unicode number & HTML code respectively are 'U+222B' and '& #8747;' I can display the symbol by printing the HTML code like below.

```
echo "& #8747;"; //Displays Integral [∫] symbol if we remove space after Ampersand.
```

But with Unicode number, Can we achieve the same? because in one of my website characters are not encoding properly. It just displays Unicode numbers like below.

```
%u03A8 %u0D24 etc.
```

Please share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
%u03A8 %u0D24 etc.
```

This looks like the output of JavaScript's [`window.escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.escape) function. Change your JavaScript code to call [`window.encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead, and decode its output on the PHP side using [`urldecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) if necessary.

If corrupted strings are already stored in your database, you could try to clean them up using code similar to this:

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('/(?:%u[0-9A-F]{4})+/', function ($m) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(
        hex2bin(str_replace('%u', '', $m[0])), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
}, $s );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work with your customers, but worth a try:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval(0x0D24) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Comment: This could be a comment.. no need for an answer.

Comment: @silkfire The equivalent Unicode character for %u0D24 & %u03A8 are 'ത' & 'Ψ' respectively. But your solution gives '¨ $'!

Comment: Sorry. Can you try my third solution?

Comment: @silkfire Thanks. Now it displaying properly. But I think It was coming in unicode numbers (%u0D24) because of Javascript function pointed out by @ PleaseStand

Comment: Okay. Just choose which answer that suits you best. Accept and upvote.